# Project Euler #1: Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: algorithm, sum

Problem: Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

My code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int sum=0;
    for(int num=0; num<1000; num++){
        if(num%3==0 || num%5==0) sum += num;
    }


    System.out.println(sum);
```

It works just right, and I saw many others are using the same approach to this problem. But if the upper limit is 1000000000000 it's gonna take a while. So I want to know what kind of approach can be more efficient to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg: yes! more efficient algorithms!

Comment: It can be calculated in constant time without loops. Before looking at the answer in the duplicate question linked above, see if you can work out how that could be done.